# Creating a portable Docker

Tags: linux, docker, portable

so I just got the task to create a portable Docker on an external HDD. 
So not just saving the images on them, make it so that you can start and use it from the HDD. And it has to be on Linux, so no magic windows tricks.

I already tried to use the [binaries](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/) but I got errors when I try to start dockerd:

1. `could not change group /var/run/docker.sock to docker: group docker not found`

   I think I resolved this with putting the ID of a group on my pc as an argument:

   `sudo ./dockerd --group 5001`
2. `Failed to start containerd: exec: "containerd": executable file not found in $PATH`

Here im Stuck now, I can't figure out how to get this solved.

Any ideas how to solve this error?
Or any other suggestions on how to create a portable docker for linux?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a bootable USB stick with the whole system on it.

Comment: this is sadly not an option, I don't know the usecase for it, just got the task

Comment: I think I have to build the complete envirement for it on the hdd, anybody knows what you need for this?

Comment: Why is it not an option if you don't know the usecase? Get some information about that usecase because you might be able to get something that runs on your system but if you don't know anything about the usecase it might not run where it's supposed to run. As it's reliant on kernel and hardware features this becomes even more important. Building a complete environment is creating a bootable USB drive (a really complete environment).

Comment: Normally I would totally agree with you, the problem is that I can't do that. My boss just said I have to do this with these restrictions (no bootable system, linux). Regarding usecase, he just said that it has to work everywhere, if he would like to shpi it to someone that he can plug it in and it works. He said he did it once, but doesn't remember how. And now I'm stuck and have no idea how to move on.

Answer (score 4):

Just if someone wants to do the same thing, I managed to do it.

I downloaded the binaries onto the external HDD and made a sh script which changes the PATH variable like this:

```
#/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/docker;
$(pwd)/docker/dockerd --data-root $(pwd)/dataroot --storage-driver aufs &
```

Just execute this with sudo and the docker will start. I added the --data-root Option to also save the images on the HDD.

Hope I could help someone with this.